# I killed rvm now I have a bash message

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm, implode

I decided to kill rvm, using the rvm `implode` command.

When I run `cd` in osx terminal  I get this message:

```
 ~/projects $ cd
-bash: /Users/boris/.rvm/scripts/initialize: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/boris/.rvm/scripts/hook: No such file or directory
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First of all close all terminals and open them again. If that didn't work, edit your .bash_profile (check .bashrc to be sure) and remove all lines that have to do with rvm. Then close out the terminal and open it again in order to reload bash.

Also, remove ~/.rvm just to be sure.

Comment: You can also do "source .bash_profile" after editing the file in order to reload it. There is no need to close and re-open the terminal window.

Comment: @Deleteman: But that won't remove the things that shouldn't be there, it will only reset what is in your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @muistooshort Just to clarify, it won't reset your .bash_profile content, it will reload it's content into the environment. But then again, you might be right about the no removing what shouldn't be there part.. can't try it right now, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Deleteman: I'm just thinking that there might be leftover aliases and the like that you might want to get rid of.

Comment: @muistooshort, you are right. I faced the same problem. Even after running `source` commands I was facing the issue so I closed the terminal and opened it again.

Answer (score 6):

Ingenu is correct, once you remove RVM you will need to close out the terminal session or shell session in order to completely wipe out all RVM related environment variables and settings.